# Center of an $R$-order in a central simple $F$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, quaternions

I'd like to show that

> Let $R$ be a domain with the field of fraction $F$. Let $\mathcal{O}$ be an $R$-order in a $F$-algebra $B$. When $B$ is central simple, $Z(\mathcal{O})=R$.

I saw that $Z(\mathcal{O})=\mathbb{Z}$ for quaternion algebra $B$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, so I suppose this is true in other finite dimensions.

Since an order contains a $F$-basis of $B$, we have that $Z(\mathcal O) \subset Z(B)=F$.

I don't know whether it's now elementary to prove that $Z(\mathcal{O})=R$. Wedderburn's theorem can be used to show that $F$-algebra is quaternion if and only if it is central simple algebra of dimension $4$. I'm wondering if it might be helpful to prove this statement as well.

Comment: What do you know about O intersect F?

Comment: @Kimball Hmm if I assume $R$ is commutative, which is the case in the example, $R=Z(R)=Z(\mathcal{O} \cap F)=Z(\mathcal{O}) \cap F= Z(\mathcal{O})$?

Comment: Usually domain assumes commutative (if not, what do you mean by the field of fractions).  And probably you want to assume that R is the ring of integers $O_F$ of F.  Otherwise if you can have $Z(O) = O_F \ne R$.